# Join an image into POJO on the server and then persisting using Hibernate?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, servlets, file-upload

in a question(here [Placing an image in an object, sending the object over rpc and then using hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301070/placing-an-image-in-an-object-sending-the-object-over-rpc-and-then-using-hiberna)), someone told me

1. Capture non-binary fields (text) into the POJO. I.e. a form.
2. Transfer the object using GWT RPC to the server.
3. Upload image to server.
4. Join the image into the POJO on the server.
5. Save to database.

to be able to persist a file with hibernate.

I got an answer but I am not being able to know how to access the image on the server and join that with the hibernate object so that I can persist it on the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options:

- store the file on disk and set its path in the entity
- save the file in db (less preferable) in a blob. That would require setting a byte array in the entity

if you require more than one file per entity, you'd need a collection

Comment: Ya that's ok but on the server after uploading the file, how to place the uploaded file in the byte array of the entity because the file upload is handled by another servlet (here http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/wiki/GwtUpload_GettingStarted)